# Activities stack, singleTask, navigation

Tags: android, android-activity, android-actionbar

I have 3 activities(A,B,C). For navigation from B->A and C->B with up button I use NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
What I want to achieve is navigation:
A->B->C When I am in C I want start A and pass some data in extras to A. Challenge is to keep B,C in stack so hardware back button from A will go back to C.

I tried default launchMode then singleTask launchMode.
default launchMode:
Problem is that when I navigate e.g from B->A(with up button) A activity is recreated. I want only go back in stack as it's with hardware back button.

When I used singleTask for A,B,C activities are not recreated but I can't go back from A to C.

Any suggestions how to solve it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not very clear, I'm assuming that if your stack is currently

```
A->B->C
```

and you want to start `A` from `C` and pass it some data in the extras, you then want the stack to look like this:

```
B->C->A
```

To do this, you just need to start `A` from `C` like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, A.class);
intent.putExtra("key", "value); // Your extras
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will move the existing instance of `A` from the bottom to the top of the stack and call `onNewIntent()` on that instance of `A` with the new `Intent` containing the "extras". When the user presses BACK, this will finish `A` and go back to `C`.